# Group element inside array by value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this result in my javascript API, to calculate some other things I need to group elements my date . Result is like this :

```
[
  "2020-01-24 08:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 14:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 12:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 09:00:00",
  "2020-01-22 09:00:00",
  "2020-01-22 13:00:00"
]
```

I have to group like this :

```
[ "2020-01-24": 1 value,
  "2020-01-23": 3 value,
  "2020-01-22": 2 value ]
```

i need also, to search inside the array and each value which has value >= 3 to put in other array

Comment: Ok, we now know that you have to group, but what you've tried? What is the issue that is stoping you from doing this?

Comment: Also, what does `1 value`, `3 value` means? You want to add a string saying how many values are grouped? An array with the values or just a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce`, in it, iterate the array and keep on increasing the value in the accumulator.

```js
var x = [
  "2020-01-24 08:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 14:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 12:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 09:00:00",
  "2020-01-22 09:00:00",
  "2020-01-22 13:00:00"
];

const formattedDate = x.reduce((acc,el) => {
  const date = el.split(" ")[0];
  acc[date] = (acc[date] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: thank you that work . can you help how to catch one by one the data and to pass in other array that which have value>3 for example

Answer (score 0):

Use https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

```
const array = [
  "2020-01-24 08:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 14:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 12:00:00",
  "2020-01-23 09:00:00",
  "2020-01-22 09:00:00",
  "2020-01-22 13:00:00"
]

const result = _.groupBy(array, element => element.split(' ')[0])
```